# SQL Search multiple fields with one search string

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I'm trying to allow users to utilize a single search box to search numerous fields. This is a SQL Server 2008 database that I want to query with a stored procedure. The number of fields could be 10-15. The way I have below does work, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. Any advice or recommendations of other methods would be appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field1 + field2 + CAST(field3 AS nvarchar) 
      like '%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

Comment: LIKE is slow, no matter the number of columns. Note that col1's end together with col2's start might match... (It's columns, not fields!)

Comment: You need to research "SQL parametised dynamic query" - you basically need to build up your search query as text based on the parameters that have been supplied - then pass in your parameters that removes any SQL injection vulnerabilities and then execute your query

Comment: @jarlh Good point. Thanks (yes, I should have said columns! whoops!!)

Comment: LIKE as a search predicate does not mean poor performance. LIKE with a leading wildcard means poor performance. Why not just use field1 = Searchstring OR field2 = SearchString....

Comment: @SeanLange Do you think that would faster? Seems like it might be better to only have to compare once. Also, I can't use = instead of like unless I'm looking for exact matches, correct?